# Importing LinearModelPredictiveController error: Not Found

Tags: drake

We are having difficulty importing the LinearModelPreidictiveController, which we found in the Drake documentation.

We tried from pydrake.all import LinearModelPredictiveController, and also tried from pydrake.all import Controllers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loe8I.png)
We get the following error (exact same for both)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma5aQ.png)
How can we import this class? And if we can't import it, is there a different class that can be used for MPC?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that class is not bound in python, and I'm reluctant to bind it because it [needs to be updated (or removed)](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13248).